# overload setters decorator in python

Tags: python, class, oop, decorator, python-decorators

In my class I have an array as an attribute. Using setter decorator I want to assign a values in different ways to the same attribute:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self._x=[0,0,0,0]

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = [value,value,value,value]

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value1,value2):
        self._x[0] = value1
        self._x[3] = value2
```

So, if a number is assigned, all elements are changed, if two numbers are assigned, I change the first one and the last one. Is it proper way to do that?

Comment: You can use default argument values to reduce the code. Example,  `def x(self, value1,value2=None)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python doesn't support overloading, because it doesn't need to. You **normally** use keyword parameters with defaults instead:

```
def x(self, value1, value2=None):
    if value2 is None:
        self._x = [value1] * 4
    else:
        self._x[0] = value1
        self._x[3] = value2
```

However, a *setter* on a property only ever takes **one** argument, the value; you'd have to detect passing in a sequence instead:

```
@x.setter
def x(self, value):
    if not isinstance(value, tuple):
        self._x = [value] * 4
    else:
        if len(value) == 2:
            # use indices 0 and 1, rest is discarded?
            self._x[0], self._x[3] = value[0], value[1]
        elif len(value) == 4
            self._x = value
        else:
            raise ValueError('Can only set x to a single value, or a tuple of length 2 or 4')
```

Comment: You can also use `Ellipsis` as a sentinel. It has no use in standard Python, and it's a unique singleton.

Comment: @Antimony: Sure; but that doesn't add anything, documentation wise, and would really only serve to confuse. I rather declare an explicit sentinel.

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't have any notion of overloading functions based on signature. If you want to do that, you have to do it inside the function. You could do something like this.

```
@x.setter
def x(self, value, *args):
    if args:
        self._x[0] = value
        self._x[3] = args[0]
    else:
        self._x = [value,value,value,value]
```

Comment: I don't think this will work as a setter for a property.  You'd have to look at `value` and see if it is a tuple and react accordingly ..

Comment: @mgilson, Ah, I'm not familiar with how properties work. I just went with the code sample in the OP.